# Incrementing pointer on string results in pointer to char not on string

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic, post-increment, pre-increment

I've got this code to get familiar with C:

```
char txt[] = "Thanksfor4lltheFish";
char *ptr = &txt[2];

printf("%c\n", ++*ptr++);
```

I expected to increase the pointer by 2 and print "k" but I get "b" which isn't even in this string. Why?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [table on operator precendence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this code snippet

```
char txt[] = "Thanksfor4lltheFish";
char *ptr = &txt[2];
```

the pointer `ptr` points to the third character of the array text that is to the character `'a'`.

This expression

```
++*ptr++
```

logically is equivalent to the following sequence of statements

```
char *tmp = ptr;
++ptr;
char c = *tmp;
++c;
```

As a result the character `'a'` pointed to by the pointer `ptr` is incremented and you get the character `'b'`.

The value of the expression with the post-increment operator

```
ptr++
```

is the value of the pointer `ptr` before incrementing it. That is you get the address of the character 'a'. Then this temporary expression with the address of the character `'a'` is dereferenced

```
*ptr++
```

and you get the character `'a'` itself that in turn is incremented

```
++*ptr++
```

That is the first post-increment operator is applied to the pointer `ptr`. The second pre-increment operator is applied to the pointed character `'a'` after dereferencing the value returned by the first post-increment operator.

If you wanted to get the expected by you result you could use the following expression in the call of `printf`

```
*( ptr += 2 )
```

In C++ (but not in C) you may also write

```
*++++ptr
```

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thanks a lot. It seems I have restored your updates.